# Facebook аpp approval for social plugin

Tags: facebook, plugins

I want to get approval for my app id only for the like and share buttons of facebook but it seems that it got more complicated then before.

When I go to my app then javascript sdk to create the code of javascript for my site it shows

This app is in Development Mode and not available publicly.
Modo público can be enabled in the App Dashboard.

So then I go to the app dashboard and it is asking a lot of information I don't have because it's only to have the like button in my site I don't want to read more likes of users.

So anyone can help me to find the right way to do this.

Comment: You don't need to get reviewed to just use the social plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you should have to fill in to make the app public is the Contact Email on the main Settings page:

[image: Contact Email]
<sub>(source: [infused.org](http://public.infused.org/stackoverflow/facebook_contact_email.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread whilst having the same problem.  In addition to infused's post, you have to go to "status and review" and turn "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" to Yes.

Furthermore, I noticed that removing the app id (as per the code you get if you are not logged in and go to the plugin generator page), then the code does not work at all.

Also, if the app is not set as live, then it will still sometimes work - just to make things harder to debug.